# How to simulate an approximation of pi with Numba?

Tags: python, math, numba, pi

I would like to approximate the value of pi using a Monte Carlo method, with different input points (10, 10**1 and so on) and get the code faster with Numba.

Here as follows, there is a simulation with inputs = 10

```
import numba
from random import *
import math
from math import sqrt

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def go_fast(pi): 
    inside = 0
    inputs =10
    for i in range(0,inputs):
        x=random()
        y=random()
        if sqrt(x*x+y*y)<=1:
            inside+=1
            pi=4*inside/inputs 
            return (pi)

pi = math.pi      
go_fast(pi)
```

I would just like to make sure that the simulation was correctly set since the result get from here seems a bit misleading. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
def go_fast(pi): 
    inside = 0
    inputs =10
    for i in range(0,inputs):
        x=random()
        y=random()
        if sqrt(x*x+y*y)<=1:
            inside+=1
            pi=4*inside/inputs 
            return (pi)
```

would terminate as soon as x, y for which `sqrt(x*x+y*y)<=1` hold will be encountered, in other words number of turns of your `for` loop is not deterministic (any value between 1 and 10). If you want constant number of turns of said `for` you need to put `return` *outside* body of said loop, this also apply to `pi` calucation as it should be done *after* data is collected, that is your code should be

```
def go_fast(pi): 
    inside = 0
    inputs =10
    for i in range(0,inputs):
        x=random()
        y=random()
        if sqrt(x*x+y*y)<=1:
            inside+=1
    pi=4*inside/inputs 
    return pi
```